# Assembly code throwing a stack overflow error and I can't find why

Tags: assembly, stack-overflow

I'm working on a project for a course and I have to program something in Assembly, I'm working with the PIC 16F887, I know it has a 8 level stack and I can't find why/where I'm going over it.

The code looks something like this:

```
targ_temp   EQU 0x20        
CONT1       EQU 0x20
CONT2       EQU 0x21
TTEMPU      EQU 0x22
TTEMPD      EQU 0X23
aux     EQU 0X24
FLAGS       EQU 0X25
TEMPU       EQU 0X26
TEMPD       EQU 0X27
PESO        EQU 0X28
CONT        EQU 0X30


;**********************************************************************
        
    ORG     0x000             
    goto    main              
    ORG     0x004             
    BTFSC INTCON,2
    CALL TIMEROVERFLOW
    BTFSC INTCON,1
    CALL SENSORVASO
    BTFSC INTCON,0
    CALL LEERTECLADO
    BTFSC PIR1,6
    CALL CONVERSOR
    ;BTFSC PIR1,5
    ;CALL EUSARTRECIEVE
    ;BTFSC PIR1,4
    ;CALL EUSARTTRANSMIT
    // clearing flags
    retfie                    ; return from interrupt
main
    //setup
    GOTO $
LEERTECLADO                       ;polling the keypad
    call DELAY
    movlw 0x0F
    iorwf PORTC,1
    MOVLW 0XFF    ;I use this to check at the end if a button is actually pressed, or if it was let go/pressed some other key that I'm not mapping
    BCF PORTC,3
    BTFSS PORTB,7 ;<- this is where the stack overflow originates from
    movlw 0x1
    BTFSS PORTB,6
    movlw 0x2
    BTFSS PORTB,5
    movlw 0x3
    BTFSS PORTB,4
    goto tempres
    clrf PORTC
    bsf PORTC,3
    bcf PORTC,2
    BTFSS PORTB,7
    movlw 0x4
    BTFSS PORTB,6
    movlw 0x5
    BTFSS PORTB,5
    movlw 0x6
    BTFSS PORTB,4
    goto tempset
    clrf PORTC
    BSF PORTC,2
    BCF PORTC,1
    BTFSS PORTB,7
    movlw 0x7
    BTFSS PORTB,6
    movlw 0x8
    BTFSS PORTB,5
    movlw 0x9
    clrf PORTC
    BSF PORTC,1
    BCF PORTC,0
    BTFSS PORTB,6
    movlw 0x0
    BCF PORTC,3
    BCF PORTC,2
    BCF PORTC,1
    BCF PORTC,0
    addlw 0x1           ;here I check if w overflows, if it does it means no buttons were pressed
    btfsc STATUS,2      ;
    goto term           ;
    sublw 0x1           ;if it didn't overflow I bring it back to the original value
    movwf aux
    movf TTEMPU,0
    movwf TTEMPD
    movf aux,0
    movwf TTEMPU
    goto term
tempset movlw 0X26
    movwf FSR
    BCF PORTA,7
    BSF PORTA,6
    BCF STATUS,7
    BCF STATUS,6
    goto term
tempres clrf TTEMPU
    clrf TTEMPD
    MOVLW 0x22
    movwf FSR
    BCF PORTA,7
    BSF PORTA,6
    BCF STATUS,7
    BCF STATUS,6        
term    return
CONVERSOR   
    BTFSC FLAGS,6
    GOTO SERV
    CLRF TEMPD
    CLRF TEMPU
    MOVLW .25
adec    SUBWF ADRESH,1
    INCF TEMPD,1
    BTFSC STATUS,0
    GOTO over
    BTFSS STATUS,2
    GOTO adec
    GOTO tempter
over    DECF TEMPD,1
    ADDWF ADRESH,1
    MOVLW .10
    SUBWF TEMPD,0
    BTFSC STATUS,2
    GOTO cien
    MOVLW .3
aun SUBWF ADRESH,1
    INCF TEMPU,1
    BTFSC STATUS,0
    GOTO overun
    BTFSS STATUS,2
    GOTO aun
    GOTO tempter
overun  DECF TEMPU,1    
    GOTO tempter
cien    MOVLW .10
    MOVWF TEMPD
    CLRF TEMPU
    BCF PORTA,4
    GOTO FINADC
tempter MOVF TEMPD,0
    SUBWF TTEMPD,0
    BTFSC STATUS,0
    GOTO apagar
    BTFSS STATUS,2
    GOTO mant
    MOVF TEMPU,0
    SUBWF TTEMPU,0
    BTFSC STATUS,0
    GOTO apagar
    BTFSS STATUS,2
    GOTO apagar
mant    BSF PORTA,4
    BCF FLAGS,7
    GOTO FINADC
apagar  BCF PORTA,4
    BSF FLAGS,7
    GOTO FINADC
SERV    
    MOVLW PESO
    SUBWF ADRESH,0
    BTFSC STATUS,0
    GOTO VLLENO
    BTFSS STATUS,2
    GOTO VLLENO
    GOTO FINADC
VLLENO  BCF FLAGS,6
    BCF PORTA,5
    BCF ADCON0,3
    INCF CONT,1
    MOVFW CONT
    BANKSEL TXREG
    MOVWF TXREG
    BSF TXSTA,5
    BANKSEL CONT
FINADC  BSF ADCON0,1
    RETURN
SENSORVASO
    call DELAY
    BTFSS FLAGS,7
    GOTO ENDVASO
    BSF PORTA,5
    BSF FLAGS,6
    BSF ADCON0,3
ENDVASO return
TIMEROVERFLOW   
    btfsc PORTA,7
    goto inver
    incf FSR,1
    movf INDF,0
    call TABLA
    movwf PORTD
    BCF PORTA,6
    BSF PORTA,7
    goto termi
inver   
    DECF FSR,1
    movf INDF,0
    call TABLA
    movwf PORTD
    BCF PORTA,7
    BSF PORTA,6
termi   
    return
TABLA
    ADDWF PCL,F 
    RETLW b'11111100'   ;devuelve 0
    RETLW b'01100000'   ;1
    RETLW b'11011010'   ;2
    RETLW b'11110010'   ;3
    RETLW b'01100110'   ;4
    RETLW b'10110110'   ;5
    RETLW b'10111110'   ;6
    RETLW b'11100000'   ;7
    RETLW b'11111110'   ;8
    RETLW b'11110110'   ;9
    RETLW b'11111010'   ;.0
DELAY                       ;delay routine mainly for debouncing 
    movlw .3
    movwf CONT2
ext
    movlw .250
    movwf CONT1
int
    decfsz CONT1,1
    goto int
    decfsz CONT2,1
    goto ext
    return
    END
```

Please excuse the tags in spanish, I get a stack overflow warning when simulating on proteus and touching the button that connects RB7 and RC3, also implemented it on a breadboard and had (I believe) the same thing happens, meaning that from what I could see the displays stopped switching and only one would get stuck with the same value displayed regardless of what I did.

I was using proteus to check everything was working as intending before moving it to the board until I came across this. The exact error it launches is: [PIC16 CORE] PC=0x00E9. Stack overflow executing CALL instruction. [U1]
I tried debugging on MPLAB X using the asyncronous stimulus, I followed the code line by line and it worked as intended. One thing I read on another forum as a response to someone having a similar issue was that the value added in tabla (adding it to pc) could be negative and it could go to a different call and overflow that way, but I can't see that happening here since it's a piece of code on a interrupt, so it can't be cut short, and it either places a value between 0-9 or it returns. I'll leave a chunk of code that I don't really think is necessary but maybe there's something there I'm not seeing. I'm at a loss.

Comment: I don't know if I'm fully understanding your answer, but (to the best of my knowledge) org 0x00 is the vector where the pic starts executing instructions, so I send it to main, and goto $ is a "goto same line", it stays there indefinitely. Interrupts stop the program where it is, save the pc on the stack and executes from the 0x04 vector until it returns. And I'd love to be able to use higher levels of abstraction, but sadly assembly is like programming from the ground up.

Answer (score 2):

The Stack Overflow happened in the `TIMEROVERFLOW` function/routine, I can't attest to why, but using the pointer and indirect addressing was sending a wrong W reg value calling TABLA, which led to the pc going places it shouldn't, even though I initialized the values as 0 in the setup. I replaced the routine with a flag that checks what I'm trying to show instead of relying on the pointer and I'm not getting the stack overflow anymore.

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a forum, so I've edited out the "Thank you" and other social chat that doesn't answer the question. See ["Do not use signature, taglines, greetings, thanks, or other chitchat."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior). You now have enough rep to [upvote](/help/voting) and/or [accept](/help/accepted-answer) any answers you find helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it certainly *looks* like you only ever use three levels (the interrupt itself, the call to the specific handler function, and a call from some of them to delay)<sup>(1)</sup>.

All I can suggest is that you first figure out which piece of code is at `0x00e9`, the address listed in the stack overflow error message. That may provide a clue.

Then perhaps put some protection code at the start of `TABLA` so that it only does the add for specific acceptable value. If not, do something else, such as choose a default value or enter another infinite loop like your `main: goto $` one. Hopefully you can then pick it up by virtue of a never changing PC on the address bus.

That seems to me to be the only vector for calling outside of your normal (three-level) pathways. For example, the `addw pcl, f` *may* end up effectively jumping back to somewhere in the interrupt routine and once again calling one of the handler functions. Do that a couple of times and, bang, there's your stack exhausted.

Depending on how good your emulators are, you may be able to track every single value of the program counter and see where it's going.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> The in-circuit debugger may add another level but that's *still* only four, well within the limit of eight for the `16F877`.